# OneDrive API: Getting Internal server Error while using action.createLink for a shared file

Tags: onedrive

I am trying to create a publicly shared link for OneDrive files.

I have got `onedrive.readwrite` scope from the `onedrive account(A)`.

I tried creating a sharing link for the `Account A's` file using the following call,

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{normal_file_id}/action.createLink
```

and it worked. I got the `web url` and the status is `200`.

Then I shared another `Account B's` folder with `Account A`.

Now,

I tried the same by creating a sharing link for the `Account A's`  shared file of `Account B` using the following call,

```
https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/{shared_file_id}/action.createLink
```

Now, I am getting internal server error with status `500`.

I tried both these scenarios in [Apigee console](https://apigee.com/OneDrive/embed/console/OneDrive). getting the same trouble.

Interestingly when I look into the sharing info for the file in Onedrive. I can see a Sharing link created for that file in the name of Apigee Api console.

[image: Link for apigee]

But, I am always getting 500 errors while working in API. How to rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a bug in the API. The error is happening after link creation but before the API call returns which is why the link is successfully created. Please use the issue you opened on GitHub to track: https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/237